# How do I call template defs with names only known at runtime in the Python template language Mako?

Tags: python, templates, mako

I am trying to find a way of calling def templates determined by the data available in the context.

**Edit:** A simpler instance of the same question.

It is possible to emit the value of an object in the context:

```
# in python
ctx = Context(buffer, website='stackoverflow.com')

# in mako
<%def name="body()">
I visit ${website} all the time.
</%def>
```

Produces:

```
I visit stackoverflow.com all the time.
```

I would like to allow a customization of the output, based upon the data.

```
# in python 
ctx = Context(buffer, website='stackoverflow.com', format='text')

# in mako
<%def name="body()">
I visit ${(format + '_link')(website)} all the time. <-- Made up syntax.
</%def>

<%def name='html_link(w)'>
<a href='http://${w}'>${w}</a>
</%def>

<%def name='text_link(w)'>
${w}
</%def>
```

Changing the `format` attribute in the context should change the output from

```
I visit stackoverflow.com all the time.
```

to

```
I visit <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a> all the time.
```

The **made up syntax** I have used in the `body` `def` is obviously wrong. What would I need to dynamically specify a template, and then call it?

Comment: Could you describe what your goal is?  Clearly, this is convoluted -- and there's something you'd like to accomplish that might be done more simply.  What's the reason for trying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes some playing with mako's `local` namespace, but here's a working example:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.runtime import Context
from StringIO import StringIO

mytemplate = Template("""
<%def name='html_link(w)'>
<a href='http://${w}'>${w}</a>
</%def>
<%def name='text_link(w)'>
${w}
</%def>
<%def name="body()">
I visit ${getattr(local, format + '_link')(website)} all the time.
</%def>
""")

buf = StringIO()
ctx = Context(buf, website='stackoverflow.com', format='html')
mytemplate.render_context(ctx)
print buf.getvalue()
```

As desired, this emits:

```
I visit 
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a>
 all the time.
```

Comment: This is almost precisely what I was looking for. Replacing local with self works well with inheritances too.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you first generate the template (from another template :), and then run that with your data?